# Unlock/lock form objects with vba

Tags: vba, combobox, scrollbar

I have an excel worksheet with 2 comboboxes, and 3 scrollbars. I want to protect all the sheet except this form objects (and one cell). When i try to protect the sheet, i can't use the scrollbars and comboboxes. How can i unlock them, keepin the protection for the rest of the sheet with vba ? I tried to unlock the cells linked to the form objects but it still doesn't work.

Thank u

AB

Comment: Have you unchecked the Locked property on the comboboxes and scrollbars themselves? (Right-click, Format Control... Protection tab)

Comment: yeah i did but it changes anything. I have this message (translated from french) when i click on a scrollbar:
"the cell or the graph is protected and is read-only"

Comment: i put this code to unlock the cell i wanted to unlock but i don't know how to use it to unlock form objects..

Private Sub Verrouillage()
With Worksheets("Feuil1")
    .Cells.Locked = True
    .Range("D4").Locked = False
    .Protect
End With
End Sub

Comment: ok i think i found a solution using the previous code and adding all the references of the cells which are linked to my form objects (Range("cell").Locked = False) .. it seems to work but i would want users not to type in this linked cells

Comment: Is the cell that's linked to the combobox unlocked? That is, the cell that gets updated when you select a value from the combobox? I don't have

Comment: oops, continued from previous comment... I don't have any problems using a combobox on a protected sheet, provide the linked cell is not locked.

Comment: yeah i don't have any problems too if i unlock the linked cells... BUT , i don't want this linked cell unlocked cause i don't want users to write in it !!!

Comment: if i resume : users can use scrollbars and combos but can't type in the linked cells, and all the sheet has to be protected except one cell. that's what i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put the cells that need to be modified on a very hidden worksheet.

Create a named range e.g. "InputCell" in a separate worksheet e.g. "SheetWithInputCell". Set the cell link of the combobox to the named range using =InputCell.

Then set the worksheet to VeryHidden. VeryHidden means that users can't right-click on the sheet tabs and unhide it.

To set the sheet to very hidden, go to the VBA IDE (Alt+F11) and look at the Properties window. If you can't see the Properties window, select View > Properties Window.

In the Project Explorer window (View > Project Explorer), select the worksheet to hide and set the Visible property to xlSheetVeryHidden.

Then you can leave the hidden sheet unprotected and lock the sheet with the controls.

Comment: yeah that's what i decided to do.. in fact i put the linked cells in an hidden column and unlock this cells in my code (users can't make appear the columns when the sheet is protected) and i linked this hidden cells to others in my sheet in order to show the values that the user chooses.. but this cells are protected.

Answer (score 0):

What about Menu option Data --> Allow Users to Edit Ranges?

Comment: don't find the menu, my excel is in french. This menu is in excel or visual basic editor ? Actually i just want they can use my scrollbars and comboboxes when i protect my sheet (the cells linked to the form objects have to be protected too)

Comment: Apologies. It's the menu option next to Data in Excel.
Tools --> Protection --> Allow Users to Edit Ranges

I'm also using 2003.